# Elementary question: is $\langle a|b \rangle$ the same as $\langle a||b\rangle$?

Tags: terminology-and-notation

In trying to learn more about quantum computing, one of the first things encountered is a definition of the inner product $\langle a|b\rangle$. If I interpret it correctly, and looking near the bottom of page 15 of the [2011 book by Rieffel and Polak](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/quantum-computing), this notation is shorthand for writing $\langle a||b\rangle$. Is that correct, or is my understanding flawed?

It may seem as though it is obvious (or obviously wrong), but so far I have found it strangely rare to see this explicitly stated.  I would welcome some confirmation or correction.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your understanding is correct. $\langle a | b \rangle$ is shorthand for $\langle a||b\rangle$. [Here](https://cds.cern.ch/record/1522001/files/978-1-4614-6336-8_BookBackMatter.pdf) is a good resource for linear algebra and Dirac notation for quantum computing.